# How to add text at end of each line in charts.js

Tags: charts, chart.js

[image]

How can i add text at each line end like 97th, 95th etc using  **charts.js**. Any help would be great. I tried documentation and did googling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [extend](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html#extending-existing-chart-types) line controller drawing serie labels at the end of each line:

```js
var chartData = {
  datasets: [{
    label: 'serie1',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)',
    data: [{x: 1, y: 10}, {x: 2, y: 12}, {x: 3, y: 18}, {x: 4, y: 5}, {x: 5, y: 25}, {x: 6, y: 30}]
  },
  {
    label: 'serie2',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(120, 0, 190, 0.6)',
    data: [{x: 1, y: 8}, {x: 2, y: 9}, {x: 3, y: 16}, {x: 4, y: 8}, {x: 5, y: 12}, {x: 6, y: 20}]
  },
  {
    label: 'serie3',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 200, 10, 0.6)',
    data: [{x: 1, y: 10}, {x: 2, y: 5}, {x: 3, y: 26}, {x: 4, y: 18}, {x: 5, y: 19}, {x: 6, y: 10}]
  }]
};

var originalController = Chart.controllers.line;
Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw: function() {
    originalController.prototype.draw.call(this, arguments);
    drawLabels(this);
  }
});

function drawLabels(t) {
 ctx.save();
  ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(12, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom'; 

  var chartInstance = t.chart;
  var datasets = chartInstance.config.data.datasets;
  datasets.forEach(function(ds, index) {
    var label = ds.label;
    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(index);
    var len = meta.data.length-1;
    //console.log(ds, meta.data[len]._model);    
    var xOffset = meta.data[len]._model.x+10;
    var yOffset = meta.data[len]._model.y;
    ctx.fillText(label, xOffset, yOffset);
  });
  ctx.restore();
}


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
   legend: { display: false },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
       type: 'linear',
        scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'x' }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: { min: 0 },
        scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'y' }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 0,
        right: 60,
        top: 20,
        bottom: 0
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#myChart {
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/q62yv516/

Comment: Thanks, Trying it now.

Comment: Yes, I tried, But the string hides as its very long. Is it possible to make the chart smaller, so that i can accommodate complete string. I did try some ways which didn't work out. Thanks for your solution brother.

Comment: If you need to create a second line chart, make sure you reset the original controller, `Chart.controllers.line = originalController`, before calling, `new Chart`, otherwise subsequent charts may be messed up.

Comment: You can change the amount of space for the text by changing options.layout.padding.right.

Comment: Great! I've found this

Answer (score 3):

```
plugins = [
    {
      id: 'customPlugin',
      beforeDraw: chart => {
        const datasets = chart.config.data.datasets;
        if (datasets) {
          const { ctx } = chart.chart;

          ctx.save();
          ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
          ctx.font = '400 12px Open Sans, sans-serif';

          for (let i = 0; i < datasets.length - 1; i++) {
            const ds = datasets[i];
            const label = ds.label;
            const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);
            const len = meta.data.length - 1;
            const xOffset = chart.canvas.width - 26;
            const yOffset = meta.data[len]._model.y;
            ctx.fillText(label, xOffset, yOffset);
          }
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
    }
  ];
```

Same as above, but as a plugin

Comment: This looks neat. I'm new to Chart.js how would this plugin be implemented? Have you  example code please?

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html